# Linq condition in list to get children elements of specific element

Tags: c#, linq

Can you help me with a lambda expression equivalent for this:

```
var q = from c in result
                from s in result
                where (c.parent == s.title) 
                where s.title=="myvalue"
                select c;
```

Unsure how to do a lambda when two tables are involved, even if it's sort of a self join

I ve tried this:

```
var newl = res.Where(yy => yy.title == "x").SelectMany(vv => vv.parent = y.title).ToList(); //wrong syntax
```

where "my value" is what the parent has on title field, but I want to calculate "my value" on the same line of code, which can render actually multiple possibilities for parents (say, 3 elements have the quality of being a parent), so I want to have 3 different results. I know I can use Skip(x).First() or something like that to take the parent of rank x, where x is a number.

Comment: Can you show your code to see what have you tried so far?

Comment: will cancel down vote after the question is explained in more detail

Comment: Did you meant something like `myList.Where(x=>x.Field1 == x.Field2)`?

Comment: for better readability you should write linq query with self join not Lambda expression, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I still dont get that what that fields is. An property of class? a string ? Parent of a xml ? Thats why they want your code.

Maybe you trying to tell something like this:

```
myList.Where(x=>x.Field1 == x.Field2 && x.Field2 == x.Field3);
```

Comment: Thank u GBursali. 
I tried sth like this: `var nl= result.Where(v => v.parent == result.Where(vv => vv.title == "parent").Skip(0).Take(1));` // because are several parents, parents are identified by keyword "parent" on field title. but syntax here is wrong...( This should give me the kids of first parent, then I would play with Skip and Take to take the kids of second and so on. )

Answer (score 0):

You are introducing a cross join and without any sample data I can't really understand your purpose. Anyway in lambda syntax it would be like:

```
var q = result.SelectMany(r => result
   .Where(re => re.title=="myvalue" && re.title == r.parent), 
   (c,s) => c);
```

EDIT: I based my answer on your code. Reading your explanations on what you are trying to do, it looks like your current Linq code is not right? Maybe you meant something like this:

```
List<Dummy> result = new List<Dummy> {
new Dummy { Id=1, parent=0, title="myvalue"},
new Dummy { Id=2, parent=0, title="myvalue"},
new Dummy { Id=3, parent=0, title="myvalue"},
new Dummy { Id=4, parent=1, title="p4"},
new Dummy { Id=5, parent=1, title="p5"},
new Dummy { Id=6, parent=2, title="p6"},
new Dummy { Id=7, parent=3, title="myvalue"},
new Dummy { Id=8, parent=0, title="value"},
new Dummy { Id=9, parent=0, title="myvalue"},
};

var q = from c in result
        from s in result
        where (c.parent == s.Id && s.title == "myvalue")
        select c;

result.SelectMany(p => result.Where(c => c.parent == p.Id && p.title=="myvalue"), 
    (prnt,child) => child);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way with self join.

```
result.Join(result,r1=>r1.parent,r2=>r2.title,(r1,r2) => new { r1, r2 })).
Where(m=>m.r2.title=="myvalue").
Select(d=>d.r1);
```